# Dual machine will not boot into Windows (but Linux works fine)

Tags: linux, windows-10, multi-boot

Folks,

I have an LG Gram 17 which works beautifully with Linux, but I can no longer boot into Windows 10 after setting up Linux. Linux was set up with UEFI. I can see the WinRE parition with Mageia control centre.)

When I try and boot into Windows it immediately tells me it's prepairing an automatic repair. Tells me to try advanced options and the Log File is d:\Recovery\blah\SrtTrail.txt. Dropping to the command line shows this file does not exist.

I have tried all the options System restore where it tells me no restore points have been created.

Startup repair gives me the same message as automatic repair.

System backup image tells me it cannot find a system image. Does that need to be done manually from Windows itself? (Please note I am a Linux user and an occasional Windows user, so I might have been very naive about it all.)

I've also tried uninstall updates.

I have done dual boot many times over the years and never had any problems, but I accept Microsoft could have done something nasty with Windows 10 that I'm completely unaware of.

Do I have any options here I've not tried yet? Or is Windows totally borked now? It's not the end of the world if it is as I rarely use it, but might be useful at some point in the future.

If there is a way of supplying extra information I'm not aware of please ask and I will supply.

Many thanks. :)

Edit: tried the suggestion below, but when trying woeusb I get this:

```
Installation failed!
Exit code: 256
Log:
/usr/bin/woeusb: line 433: local: warning: only_for_gui_ref: circular name reference
/usr/bin/woeusb: line 433: warning: only_for_gui_ref: circular name reference
/usr/bin/woeusb: line 508: warning: only_for_gui_ref: circular name reference
WoeUSB v3.1.4
==============================
Wiping all existing partition table and filesystem signatures in /dev/sdb...
/dev/sdb: 2 bytes were erased at offset 0x000001fe (dos): 55 aa
/dev/sdb: calling ioctl to re-read partition table: Success
Ensure that /dev/sdb is really wiped...
Creating new partition table on /dev/sdb...
Creating target partition...
Making system realize that partition table has changed...
Wait 3 seconds for block device nodes to populate...
mkfs.fat: warning - lowercase labels might not work properly with DOS or Windows
mkfs.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
Mounting source filesystem...
Mounting target filesystem...
Applying workaround to prevent 64-bit systems with big primary memory from being unresponsive during copying files.
Copying files from source media...
The command "dd if="${source_file}" bs="${DD_BLOCK_SIZE}" skip="${i}" seek="${i}" of="${dest_file}" count=1 2> /dev/null" failed with exit status "1", program is prematurely aborted
Resetting workaround to prevent 64-bit systems with big primary memory from being unresponsive during copying files.
/usr/bin/woeusb: line 1541: echo: write error: Invalid argument
The command "dd if="${source_file}" bs="${DD_BLOCK_SIZE}" skip="${i}" seek="${i}" of="${dest_file}" count=1 2> /dev/null" failed with exit status "1", program is prematurely aborted
```

However, it still boots to the memory stick and gives you the option to repair. It then just bombs out of it in exactly thesame way as trying it from the HDD.

I might see whether I can burn the stick from a Windows machine.

Comment: Use a Windows boot media and do Startup Repair.

Comment: Is that downloadable from somewhere? I got nothing at all with the laptop,

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a boot media for Windows 10, then use it to boot and do
Startup Repair.

- Use Linux to download the Windows 10 ISO from
  [Create Windows 10 installation media](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)
- Use `WoeUSB` to create the boot media as explained in
  [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1463983/8672).
- Boot it and choose Repair to enter and do
  [Startup Repair](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html).

Afterward, both Linux and Windows should become accessible via the boot menu.

Comment: Many thanks . I'll  give it a go and report back.

Comment: This doesn't work for me at all. Could be various reason I suppose. I've added some extra details in my question.

Comment: Strange. Where does it go wrong?

Comment: I've added details to the original question

Comment: Are you using the latest [WoeUSB 3.3.0 release](https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB/releases)? Check also what you are doing against [this answer](https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB/issues/226#issuecomment-442513556).

Comment: If I use Woeusb from the command line it tells me the stick is mounted. Which it is not. umount /dev/sdb confirms is not mounted as does Mageia control centre. Mind you it tells me the SOURCE is mounted, I assume that doesn't mean the iso? I fail to see how I can unmount that! I'm on version 3.1.4 of woeusb

Comment: The trace looks to have worked up to the "Copying" step. Try to install WoeUSB 3.3.0, which might do better.

Comment: Well, I've tried the latest version and used Rufus on another Windows 10 machine. They all do the same thing in that they just bomb out after you select repair and say they couldn't fix it. I can only assume when I resized the partition with the Mageia installer I royally screwed things up. The question is, if  I did a reinstall with that installer would it pick up my keys and would it find necessary drivers. In my experience Windows is PITA to install, although I've not done it for many years now.

Comment: Windows 10 activates using a fingerprint of the hardware. This means that if it was ever installed on this computer, activation would be automatic and no serial required. And yes, the disk might be impossible to use. If you have access to another Windows 10 computer, it would be simpler to create the boot USB from [Create Windows 10 installation media](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10).

Comment: OK, thanks Harry, much appreciate the help. I'll have a think about just how bothered I am about getting Windows on this machine. Have an upvote!